# The need for two cancellation tokens in .NET 6 Parallel.ForEachAsync?

Tags: c#, cancellation, cancellation-token, parallel.foreachasync

I was experimenting with how to break out of a `ForEachAsync` loop. `break` doesn't work, but I can call `Cancel` on the CancellationTokenSource. The signature for `ForEachAsync` has two tokens - one as a stand-alone argument and one in the `Func` body signature.

I took note that when `cts.Cancel()` is called, both the `token` and `t` variables have `IsCancellationRequested` set to true. So, my question is: what is the purpose for the two separate `token` arguments? Is there a distinction worth noting?

```
List<string> symbols = new() { "A", "B", "C" };
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

try
{
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(symbols, token, async (symbol, t) =>
    {
        if (await someConditionAsync())
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    });
catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Stopping parallel loop: {oce}");
}
finally
{
    cts.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Token passed to the body of the method invoked by `ForEachAsync` is a different one and comes from a internal [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/53d1d2c6ec322fd5eb3351982107d389c182ad46/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs#L400) which will be canceled:

- on "external" [cancelation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/53d1d2c6ec322fd5eb3351982107d389c182ad46/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs#L415) (that's why you see `t.IsCancellationRequested` set to `true` when `cts.Cancel()` is called)
- for internal reasons (one that I found - any iteration [has thrown an uncaught exception](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/53d1d2c6ec322fd5eb3351982107d389c182ad46/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs#L454), i.e. fail fast principle is applied).

So the purpose of `cancellationToken CancellationToken` argument passed to the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is to support cancellation by caller and the one passed to the asynchronous delegate invoked by it - to support cancelation both by external (i.e. caller) and internal sources (see the P.S.).

P.S.

Also note that usually it is a good idea to pass and check the token state in your methods (i.e. `await someConditionAsync(t)` with corresponding implementation inside) since `CancelationToken` is used for so called [cooperative cancelation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Answer (score -2):

`Parallel.ForEachAsync` takes a token that you can use to cancel the for-each (an input to the function), that token is also passed to each iteration of the for-each (an input to the lambda).

One of the reasons for passing in the cancellation token to the lambda is to avoid the capture of a variable that is outside of the lambda expression.

Imagine this code:

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(symbols, token, async (symbol, t) => MyCode(symbol, t));

Task async MyCode(string symbol, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (await someConditionAsync())
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
});
```

Written this way, `MyCode` has no access to `token`.

Using a lambda means you can 'inherit' variables outside the lambda, but that doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Your `MyCode` function needs to be `async Task`, not `void` - and if you do that then you may-as-well just pass `MyCode` by-name instead of instantiating an _identity function_ (and it annoys me that C# cannot elide _identity_ lambdas...)