# How to send http requests in ForEach loop with async / await

Tags: c#, async-await

The following code is a [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad) program.

- The `payloadList` contains json-objects like `{"id": 1, "foo": "one" }`.
- Each object of `payloadList` should be sent to a server with `httpClient.SendAsync()`
- The `response` for each request should be stored in `responseList`

The code below does partly work. But i do not understand why some parts are not working. I assume that the responses are not completed when `responseList.Add(foo)` is executed.

This request shall be send for each json-object `{"id": 1, "foo": "one" }`

```cs
public static async Task<string> DoRequest(HttpClient client, string payload)
{   
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
                           "http://httpbin.org/anything");
    request.Content = new StringContent(payload
                           , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");        
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request); 
    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
    return responseContent;
}
```

The `DoRequest()`-method wraps the request and can be used inside main like this

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    var responseList = new List<string>();  
    var payloadList = new List<string>{"{ 'id': 1, 'bar': 'One'}",
                                       "{ 'id': 2, 'bar': 'Two'}",
                                       "{ 'id': 3, 'bar': 'Three'}"};
        
    var client = new HttpClient();
    
    payloadList.ForEach(async (payload) => {
        var responseFoo = await DoRequest(client, payload);
        responseFoo.Dump("response"); // contains responseFoo
        responseList.Add(responseFoo);  // adding responseFoo to list fails
    });                     
    responseList.Dump();    // is empty
}
```

The responseList is empty.

- Expected `responseList.Dump()` contains all responses `responseFoo`.
- Actual `responseList` is empty.

[image: Linqpad-demo]

#### Questions

- How can each response for `await client.SendAsync(request)` be added to a responseList?
- Why is `responseList` empty despite that `foo.Dump()` works?
- How to confirm or check if every `client.SendAsync` is finished?
- Would you write the code above different - why?

Comment: ask one question at a time please. See also [ask]

Comment: `responseList.Add(foo);      // this not `...in what way does it "not work"? Is there an error?

Comment: The responseList is empty. Expected `responseList.Dump()` contains all responses `foo`. Actual `responseList` is empty.

Comment: P.S. putting `responseList.Dump();` outside the foreach loop obviously won't work because that'll run before all the async stuff is complete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete may be helpful

Comment: @Dyson how can i await that all the async stuff is done?

Comment: I already provided a link which might be helpful, if the answer below doesn't address your issue (although I think the latest edits to it are basically describing the same approach using Task.WhenAll)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List.ForEach` is not `Task`-aware and will execute everything in parallel without waiting for the results (i.e. it will create tasks for all items in `payloadList` and will continue to the next statement `responseList.Dump();` without awaiting them).

1. In newer versions of .NET you can use [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0)(for example as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249541/2501279)) combined with use of appropriate collection from `System.Collections.Concurrent`, for example `ConcurrentBag<T>`. `List` is not thread-safe and modifying it concurrently can lead to a lot of problems.

   Code can look like the following:

   ```cs
   var responseList = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

   await Parallel.ForEachAsync(payloadList, async (payload, ct) =>
   {
       var foo = await DoRequest(client, payload, ct);
       responseList.Add(foo);     
   });

   static async Task<string> DoRequest(HttpClient client, string payload, CancellationToken ct)
   {   
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://httpbin.org/anything");
       request.Content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");        
       var response = await client.SendAsync(request, ct); 
       string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct); 
       return responseContent;
   }
   ```
2. If you are fine with all requests running in parallel - just create a enumerable of tasks and use `Task.WhenAll<T>()`:

   ```cs
   var tsks = payloadList
       .Select(payload => DoRequest(client, payload));

   string[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tsks);
   ```
3. If you want to execute requests one after another - just switch to ordinary `foreach`:

   ```cs
   var responseList = new List<string>(); // no need for concurrent collection in this case 

   foreach (var payload in payloadList)
   {
       var foo = await DoRequest(client, payload);
       responseList.Add(foo);  
   }
   ```

If you want to dive deeper here some links:

- [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) documentation
- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)
- [Threading in C#](https://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari (a bit dated but still amazing)

Comment: Make sure to await  `Parallel.ForEachAsync`

Comment: Could you add some code how to use it?

Comment: Thanks for the code. One more thing. I would expect that `responseList.Add(foo)` should work. But it stays empty. Why is this the case?

Comment: @surfmuggle Potentially you app finishes before the requests are completed. And `responseList.Dump();` is executed before any request is completed with very high chance. I.e. `async`-`await` inside `List.ForEach` has no effect.

Comment: The part `Parallel.ForEachAsync()`  gets the error CS0117 'Parallel' does not contain a definition for 'ForEachAsync'

Comment: @surfmuggle then you are using older version of framework. See the updated code - the other two approaches will work.

Comment: @surfmuggle added some links which can be useful if you will want to go a bit deeper into the topic.