# How to parallelize asynchronous integration work that includes JSON deserialization?

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, parallel-processing

One question about parallel programming.

I need to POST 2 APIs (one after another) to get a Order list. First one is for getting token..

After I got the list, I need to POST 3 APIs (one after another) to integrate these Orders.

These 3 APIs don't accept arrays, so I need to send one by one. I cannot send batch data. With 1 thread it only integrates 10 orders in 1 minute. I need more performance. How can I run foreach part in parallel?

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Order_Integrator
{
    public class Program
    {

        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main()
        {

            //Auth
            var connectResponse = await client.PostAsync(connectUrl, connectContent);
            var connectResponseString = await connectResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var connect = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<connectResponse>(connectResponseString);
            
            var token = connect.Token;
            //Get Order List
            var orderResponse = await client.PostAsync(orderUrl, orderContent);
            var orderResponseString = await orderResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var orders = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<orderResponse>(orderResponseString);

            foreach (var order in orders)
            {
            
                //Get Order Details
                //Generate getOrderDetailsContent with order 
                var getOrderDetailsResponse = await client.PostAsync(getOrderDetailsUrl, getOrderDetailsContent);
                var getOrderDetailsResponseString = await getOrderDetailsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var getOrderDetails = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<getOrderDetailsResponse>(getOrderDetailsResponseString);

                //Create Order
                //Generate createOrderContent with GetOrderDetails
                var createOrderResponse = await client.PostAsync(createOrderUrl, createOrderContent);
                var createOrderResponseString = await createOrderResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var createOrder = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<createOrderResponse>(createOrderResponseString);

                //Create Log
                //Generate createLogContent with CreateOrderResponse
                var createLogResponse = await client.PostAsync(createLogUrl, createLogContent);
                var createLogResponseString = await createLogResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var createLog = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<createLogResponse>(createLogResponseString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0)

```
 var options = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20
};
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(orders, options, async (OrderNumber, ct) => {

var getOrderDetailsResponse = await client.PostAsync(getOrderDetailsUrl, getOrderDetailsContent);
    
});
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` does not work correctly with async code. Possibly you have meant [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249422/using-parallel-foreachasync/70249541#70249541)

Comment: I tried `Parallel.ForEach(orders, async order =>`  But it didn't work. I got an error while adding parameters to client `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-csrf-token", xToken);` **already exists**

Comment: This is because the client is `static`. You'll have to handle all conflicts in a `lock` or outside the `Parallel.ForEach` block.

Comment: @Guru Stron `Parallel.ForEachAsync` sounds better. But I've never had problems with the example code that I posted. it works with async code as well. Not sure what the difference is between them.

Comment: @WandererAboveTheSea the code you've posted will run all the requests at the same time, while the main advantages of using `Parallel.ForEach` is limiting concurrency.

Comment: Understood the main thread won't wait for all the requests to complete. Even though I'm using await inside `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: Here it is explained why `Parallel.ForEach` with `async` is not working: [Parallel.ForEach and async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137393/parallel-foreach-and-async-await).

Comment: CS0017: Parallel does not contain a definition for ForEachAsync

Comment: It's available in .NET 7 and .NET 6. Which one are you using?

Comment: Which one is used is not important, because that depends on the life cycle of your product, in combination with the life-cycle of [dotnet-core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

Comment: it is 4.8 I will upgrade and try again.

Comment: @AliKaraçay you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/65251949#65251949) a custom `Parallel.ForEachAsync` implementation that is compatible with the .NET Framework. But upgrading to .NET 6 or .NET 7 is preferable.

Comment: Upgraded to .NET 6. I also installed Entity Framework 6.4.4 for other SQL connections. 
Parallel.ForEach was not working for all orders. Approximately 8 of 10 orders was completed at Parallel.ForEach.
ForEachAsync works fine. Thanks @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using asynchronous code, you should be using asynchronous concurrency, not (multithreaded) parallelism. `Parallel.ForEachAsync` will do *both*, but it's not available on older runtimes.

You can do just asynchronous concurrency by using `Select` and then `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var tasks = orders.Select(async order =>
{
  //Get Order Details
  //Generate getOrderDetailsContent with order 
  var getOrderDetailsResponse = await client.PostAsync(getOrderDetailsUrl, getOrderDetailsContent);
  var getOrderDetailsResponseString = await getOrderDetailsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var getOrderDetails = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<getOrderDetailsResponse>(getOrderDetailsResponseString);

  //Create Order
  //Generate createOrderContent with GetOrderDetails
  var createOrderResponse = await client.PostAsync(createOrderUrl, createOrderContent);
  var createOrderResponseString = await createOrderResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var createOrder = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<createOrderResponse>(createOrderResponseString);

  //Create Log
  //Generate createLogContent with CreateOrderResponse
  var createLogResponse = await client.PostAsync(createLogUrl, createLogContent);
  var createLogResponseString = await createLogResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var createLog = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<createLogResponse>(createLogResponseString);

  return createLog;
}).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Stephen I just posted [a suggestion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82359 "Enable using the Parallel.ForEachAsync without a scheduler: invoke the body on the current thread") on GitHub about configuring the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` for pure asynchronous concurrency, without parallelism. Feel free to share your opinion about the suggestion, or if you have something else to add!